# (JDBI/Dropwizard) PSQLException when retrieving auto-incremented id from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, dropwizard, jdbi

I'm trying to set up a dropwizard project but I'm stuck. When I try to get the auto generated id field with @GetGeneratedKeys then I'm getting the following Exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : foo.
```

The request is a simple JSON Request

```
{"name":"foo"}
```

The INSERT into the database is successful but it seems that the statement returns the value of the name instead of the generated id. How can I solve this?

I use postgresql, and the table project contains a primary key field "id" with nextval('project_id_seq'::regclass). Here are the POJO, DAO and Resource Classes I use:

```
public class Project {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    public Project() { // Jackson deserialization }
    public Project(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    ...
}

@RegisterMapper(ProjectMapper.class)
public interface ProjectDAO {
    @SqlUpdate("insert into project (name) values (:name)")
    @GetGeneratedKeys
    public long insert(@Bind("name") String name);
}

@Path("/project")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class ProjectResource {
    ProjectDAO projectDAO;

    public ProjectResource(ProjectDAO personDAO) {
        this.projectDAO = personDAO;
    }

    @POST
    @Timed
    public Response add(@Valid Project project) {
        long newId = projectDAO.insert(project.getName());
        project.setId(newId);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED)
                       .entity(project).build();
    }
}
```

===============

## UPDATE

I just figured out that this relates to the fact that my id column isn't the first column in my table. The column name is. The problem occurs because **@GetGeneratedKeys** is using org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.FigureItOutResultSetMapper which is using org.skife.jdbi.v2.PrimitivesMapperFactory which returns org.skife.jdbi.v2.util.LongMapper.FIRST. This mapper is calling
**java.sql.ResultSet.getLong(1)** through the method extractByIndex(...) to retrieve the generated id, which isn't the id in my case...

I'll fix the issue by reorganizing the columns in the database, but I'd like to have a robust implementation if possible: Is there a way to specify the column name of the id column when using the @GetGeneratedKeys Annotation? (The org.skife.jdbi.v2.util.LongMapper class contains a also method called extractByName(...))

Comment: PostgreSQL itself directly supports a) [currval()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-sequence.html), which returns the value most recently obtained  nextval() for a sequence in your session, and b) an [optional RETURNING clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-insert.html). If your interface supports it, you'd write `insert into project (name) values (:name) returning id;`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue in the jdbi implementation and is fixed in a newer version as described in https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/issues/114